# Correctly align pattern with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]
So what, I wanna do it's to create a pattern and move it inside a rectangle or something to align it just like the star example. I was looking for a "magical" option to hide those vectors that doesn't show completely.. or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click-and-drag while holding down the grave accent (´) key on your keyboard to move the pattern within the fill shape or go Object -> Expand and click fill to attach the pattern to the fill so you can move it around. Hope that's the "magical option" you were hoping for!